# Galera SQL Cluster - reset & rejoin a node

Tags: galera

i have a three node galera cluster.
one of the nodes (its a passive not active used node) died and mysql is not able to start again on this host:

```
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-07-21T14:55:39Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning         hardware.
2023-07-21T14:55:39.744960Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012684] [InnoDB] [FATAL] is_short 0,     info_and_status_bits 0, offset 9008, o_offset 6, mismatch index 18446744073709551613,     end_seg_len 17 parsed len 3
BuildID[sha1]=d25f43b20ff93c5ab45e72e5201c79269b541a30
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
2023-07-21T14:55:39.745031Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure:     page0cur.cc:1177:ib::fatal triggered thread 139622639150848
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

i dont want to play around with recovery innodb, etc - i guess the simplest way is to delete this node and rejoin it to the cluster.

So my Question is how to "clean up" mySQL on the failed host in a way to get a full sync from the other two remaining nodes?

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

solved:

1.) disabled everything with "wsrep" in mysql config
2.) reinitialized mysql (mysqld --initialize)
3.) enabled "wsrep" config again
4.) restarted mysql
= sync is running now, state is primary again